# Unexpected behaviour adding two if(){}else{} constructs

Tags: r, if-statement

Consider the following R input:

```
if(TRUE){1}else{0} + if(TRUE){1}else{0}
```

The result is `1`, but I was expecting `2`. If I enclose each if-else statement in parentheses,

```
(if(TRUE){1}else{0}) + (if(TRUE){1}else{0})
```

then the result is `2`.

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: The second if clause is never evaluated... According to `help("if")`, `if` returns the expression evaluated, and that's it (after returning a value, an expression is done, conisder: `if(TRUE){1}else{0} + if(TRUE){print("test")}else{0}`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `else` clause doesn't end till R can identify the end of the expression. In R the `{}` aren't part of the syntax for if/else statements. The `{}` can be used anywhere you want to possibly put multiple statements. You can also do

```
if(TRUE) 1 else 0 + if(TRUE) 1 else 0
```

The `{}` aren't really meaningful. And since

```
 0 + if(TRUE) 1 else 0
```

is a valid expression, R just assumes you wanted all of that for your `else` clause. Normally R will end the else clause when it encounters a newline after a completed expression. This means that

```
if(TRUE){1}else{0} + 
   if(TRUE){1}else{0}
```

will also return the same value because the `+` at the end of the first line indicates that there's more to come because a valid expression can't end in `+`.

Note you can see how the expression is turned into the abstract syntax tree with the help of the `lobstr` package if you are really curious.

```
#lobstr::ast(if(TRUE){1}else{0} + if(TRUE){1}else{0})
o-`if` 
+-TRUE 
+-o-`{` 
| \-1 
\-o-`+` 
  +-o-`{` 
  | \-0 
  \-o-`if` 
    +-TRUE 
    +-o-`{` 
    | \-1 
    \-o-`{` 
      \-0
```

Here we see that everything is nested in the first `if`. The `+` is not the main operator.

As you've done, you can use `()` or `{}` to end the expression blocks explicitly

```
{if(TRUE){1}else{0}} + {if(TRUE){1}else{0}}
```

Consider also the case of

```
x <- 5
if(FALSE) x+1 else x+2
# [1] 7
if(FALSE) x+1 else {x}+{2}
# [1] 7
```

Note how the `x+2` is taken all together for the `else` expression. It doesn't end at the first symbol `x`.

Comment: Now I understand, I was giving the braces more meaning than they really had. Thank you!

Comment: @pglpm And, to be fair, that's how braces act in many other languages. That's just not the case with R.

Answer (score 6):

Is has something to to with operator affinity which determines the order of evaluation. Like math, parenthesis have a higher priority than multiplications with have a higher priority than plus and minus. The second part of the expression will never get evaluated and thus ignored resulting in 1 e.g. `if(TRUE){1}else{0} + message("I'll never get printed")`. Including the parenthesis will force to first evaluate both parts seperatley and then do the plus resulting in 2.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I understand the idea, but I would expect it to apply only if I omitted the curly braces. The curly braces clearly delimit where the 'else' part finishes, so it isn't clear to me why the rest is skipped.